# How to cut & paste data portion from selected cells of row A to row B cells. Expertise needed

Tags: microsoft-excel

```
            C                                               E

  GDP1-00037/ FGC UC FT                        class 4,3µm-5µm Ni Sulphamate 
  Flange 40.66X13.9X5, EN Hi-                  Per SAE AMS QQ-N-290 class 2,
  P 13µm-17µm per ASTM   (cut & paste portion) 0.1µm-0.4µm Au per ASTM 
  B733, Type V SC2, class 4,      >>>          B488-01, Type 1, Code C
```

121   3µm-5µm Ni Sulphamate Per                    Class 0.
      SAE AMS QQ-N-290 class 2,                                 .
      0.1µm-0.4µm Au per ASTM                                   .
      B488-01, Type 1, Code C                                   .
      Class 0.                                                  .
               .                                                .
               .                                                .
122            .                                                .
123            .                                                .
124            .                                                .

& so on until 922.

Comment: Does this produce the correct result in E121? `=REPLACE(C121, 1, FIND("class", C121)-1, "")`

Comment: I tried it out. It fails to produce the desired result.

Comment: Not very understanding your problem, could you explain it more clearly?